# Menu Bar, which is not at the top, but once you slide down the menu bar sticks to the top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make a menu bar like the one in 
http://showbic.com/sports/adam-milne-vs-west-indies/

In this website the menu_bar is not on the top, but when you scroll down the menu bar doesn't go up with the rest of the content, but after touching the top it stays at the top.

I know some JavaScript is used combined with the CSS, but how I don't know, please someone help me.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Can you post some code please, plus a fiddle.

Comment: @Adsy He doesn't have any...lol

Comment: @laaposto Link is living on my end

Comment: http://www.outyear.co.uk/smint/ BTW: https://www.google.com/webhp?tab=ww&ei=PhvdUrSVNYuutQb0iYHABQ&ved=0CBcQ1S4#q=jquery+scroll+sticky+menu

Comment: And if you use SMINT, feel free to drop a message on twitter @rabmyself!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667829/how-to-create-a-sticky-navigation-bar-that-becomes-fixed-to-the-top-after-scroll

Comment: You already found an example, why don't you just copy that and modify?

Answer (score 2):

I would advise trying something with `onscroll` in Javascript and then keeping the header at the top you can use `position:fixed;` in the container's CSS. (you might want to play around with the top placement or something else to keep it at the very top and in your preferred spot when not needed at the top)

See for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fixed = false;

onscroll = function() 
{
    var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    if (scrollTop > 200) 
    {
        if (!fixed) 
        {
            $('.navbar-wrapper').css({ position: 'fixed', top : 0 });
            fixed = true;
            }
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (fixed)  
        {
            $('.navbar-wrapper').css({ position: 'relative', top : 200 });
              fixed = false;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When looking into the source code, you can view the javascript part that is controlling this bar. http://showbic.com/wp-content/plugins/seo-alrp/js/slidebox.js?ver=3.8.
Instead of :

```
$('#alrp-slidebox').animate({'right':'0px'},300);
```

Put:

```
$('#yourContent').animate({'top':'0px'},300);
```

And for (we suppose that the height of the box is 300px):

```
$('#alrp-slidebox').stop(true).animate({'right':'-430px'},100);
```

Put:

```
$('#yourContent').stop(true).animate({'top':'-300px'},100);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be your `css`

```
body{
    height:1000px;
}

div{
width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    top:200px;
}

.fixedClass{
position:fixed;
top:0;
}
```

the `jquery` code

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() > 200){ // position of menu from the top 
$('div').addClass('fixedClass');
}
else{
$('div').removeClass('fixedClass');
}
})
```

the `Html` :P

```
<div>
</div>
```

the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/NhU7f/)

Comment: Thank You everyone for your time and replies, but I meant how to do it in pure javaScript, does anyone know how to do it in pure javascript ?