# How to keep a part of a page fixed on top when scroling

Tags: html, css

When the page has enough contents that it'll need to be scrolled down, the header and the menu will disappear. Now, the header **is not** a problem, but I'd really really like the menu to be kept fixed on the top of the page while still scrolling contents down.

Here I'm posting the code of a page with that header and menu

```
<html>
<head>
<noscript><meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;URL=error-no-javascript.html"></noscript>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.vtsim.com/favicon.png" />
<title>TRAINZ - VTsim.com</title>
</head>
<body ondragstart="return false" onselectstart="return false" oncontextmenu="return false" link="red" alink="red" vlink="red">
<font face="Arial" size="2" color="black">

<p align="center">
<img src="http://www.vtsim.com/image/head_trz_1.png"><a href="http://fs.vtsim.com" border="0"><img src="http://www.vtsim.com/image/head_trz_2.png"></a>
</p>

//--- now starts the menu wich I pretend to be kept fixed on top when scrolling

<p align="center">
<a href="http://trainz.vtsim.com" border="0"><img src="http://www.vtsim.com/image/b_home_a.png"></a><a href="http://trainz.vtsim.com/trains.htm" border="0"><img src="http://www.vtsim.com/image/b_trz_trains_i.png"></a><a href="http://trainz.vtsim.com/tracks.htm" border="0"><img src="http://www.vtsim.com/image/b_trz_tracks_i.png"></a><a href="http://trainz.vtsim.com/trackside.htm" border="0"><img src="http://www.vtsim.com/image/b_trz_trkside_i.png"></a><a href="http://trainz.vtsim.com/scenery.htm" border="0"><img src="http://www.vtsim.com/image/b_trz_scenery_i.png"></a><a href="http://trainz.vtsim.com/routes.htm" border="0"><img src="http://www.vtsim.com/image/b_trz_routes_i.png"></a><a href="http://trainz.vtsim.com/others.htm" border="0"><img src="http://www.vtsim.com/image/b_trz_others_i.png"></a><a href="mailto:vasco@vtsim.com" border="0"><img src="http://www.vtsim.com/image/b_email.png"></a><br />
<img src="http://www.vtsim.com/image/sep_800.png">
</p>

//--- and the menu code ended here

<p align="center">
Contents will display here
</p>

</font>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667829/how-to-create-a-sticky-navigation-bar-that-becomes-fixed-to-the-top-after-scroll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically wrap your header inside a container and with a bit of `jQuery` like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 226) {
                $(".header").addClass("fixed");
            } else {
                $(".header").removeClass("fixed");
            }
        });
```

You add a class to this container and make it `fixed` once you scroll 226px down (content over your header height).

css:

```
.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;        
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/2e9h0gxf/2/)**

Edit: TO easily implement this script in your web just add this code before the `</head>` tag in your html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 226) {
                $(".header").addClass("fixed");
            } else {
                $(".header").removeClass("fixed");
            }
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .fixed {
        position:fixed;
        width:100%;
        top:0;
        left:0;        
    }
    </style>
```

And don't forget to add the `<div class="header">` also as in the fiddle example.

Comment: This is awseome!! My question will be fully answered when I figure out where (or on wich files) should I implement the CSS and the jquery code.

I've made originally a brief presentation but it was edited and heavilly cutted where I explained that I was a complete noob for everything else than simple html and copy/paste.

Thank you in advance, but I need further help on implementation.

Comment: I edited my answer letting you know where to add the code

Answer (score 1):

The way I have done this and I think it's a pretty standard way, is to set a css class of `.fixed` on the header once the scroll position of the window reaches the top of the header.

This method requires javascript (and more specifically jQuery)!

```js
$(function() {
  createSticky(jQuery("#header"));
});

function createSticky(sticky) {

  if (typeof sticky !== "undefined") {

    var pos = sticky.offset().top,
        win = jQuery(window);

    win.on("scroll", function() {
      win.scrollTop() >= pos ? sticky.addClass("fixed") : sticky.removeClass("fixed");
    });
  }
}
```

```css
#header {
  background: #666;
  padding: 3px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 5000px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>stuff that might be above the header</p>

<div id="header">
  Home
</div>
```

## CSS Only

When browser support grows a bit you could use `position: sticky` which will basically do the same thing with no javascript. If your user demographic is Firefox however, you are good to go as Firefox has supported it for a while.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using the `scrolltop` property of DOM, position CSS property and little JavaScript code, i.e, put the `onscroll` event to body tag (o add event listener)

```
<body onscroll="calculate_top()">
```

and `id="myMenu"` in your menu

```
//--- now starts the menu wich I pretend to be kept fixed on top when scrolling
<p align="center" id="myMenu">
    . . .
    <img src="http://www.vtsim.com/image/sep_800.png">
</p>
//--- and the menu code ended here
```

and Javascript

```
function calculate_top() {
    var y = 0;    
    element=document.getElementsByTagName("body");

    y=element[0].scrollTop;
    //you can see y values while you scrolling
    console.log(" y = " + y);
    if( y > 140){//old style
        document.getElementById("myMenu").style.position='fixed';
        document.getElementById("myMenu").style.top=0+'px';
    }else{
        document.getElementById("myMenu").style.position='relative';
    }
}
```

The 140 value is the measure between top your menu and top of body on screen (you can change to what ever you need)