# How to align Navbar at bottom of window, but have content under this in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I need help with this website I'm making for a project at school. I need help with the Nav bar at the bottom of the window when you first load the page but if you scroll down it scrolls with the page. I need it to basically align to the bottom of the window when its first loaded. I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it. Here is a reference.

[Example Website](http://snoozeeatery.com/)

Notice how the Nav bar is always at the bottom of the window when scrolled to the top even if you resize the window. I would like to do this with only CSS and HTML, but I understand a little bit of Javascript so if It can't be done with only CSS and HTML it's alright. Thanks for the help.

Comment: We are here to help you learn, not to make your homework. What have you done so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a sticky navigation bar that becomes fixed to the top after scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667829/how-to-create-a-sticky-navigation-bar-that-becomes-fixed-to-the-top-after-scroll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic is in using both JQuery and CSS.

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var navBarY = $(".bottom-bar").offset().top;
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= navBarY) {
            $(".bottom-bar").addClass("fixed-top");
        } else {
            $(".bottom-bar").removeClass("fixed-top");
        }
    });
});
```

Whenever the `.bottom-bar` reaches the top of the window a class `fixed-top` is added.

**CSS**

```
.fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

**Example**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var navBarY = $(".bottom-bar").offset().top;
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= navBarY) {
            $(".bottom-bar").addClass("fixed-top");
        } else {
            $(".bottom-bar").removeClass("fixed-top");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    height: 2000px;
}
.bottom-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #2A2A2A;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-top: calc(100vh - 40px);
}
.fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="bottom-bar">Navigation bar</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot.