# header image and fixed navbar

Tags: html, css

I want to make a page that first displays a video, then under the video, I want a navbar, but when I scroll down I want the navbar to be fixed.

also, I would really like to only use CSS, no `JavaScript` and definitely no `jQuery`

This is what i have:

```css
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
        }

        li {
            float: left;
        }

        li a {
            display: block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        li a:hover {
            background-color: #111;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<video style="height:1000px " src="http://achielvolckaert.be/Slow Motion Apples Falling.mp4" autoplay></video>

<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
<p>

    Coffee is a multi-billion dollar industry that shows signs of continued growth. In the United States alone, hundreds of millions of people drink coffee on a regular basis. It can be to start their day, a midday boost to get them through the remaining hours of their day, or even a comfort drink. Whatever the reason may be, there are millions of people nationwide who have trouble functioning without the caffeine spike that coffee offers. Today, coffee companies are setting out to satisfy the desires of coffee drinkers by offering a huge and seemingly endless variety of new flavors. Of course there is the traditional cream and sugar, or lack thereof (black coffee), but now, anyone interested in trying new flavors will find a much larger selection than ever imagined. Flavors such as Hazelnut, French Vanilla, Chocolate, Dark Roast, Apple Cinnamon, Amaretto, and Butternut, are only a small fraction of what coffee companies have to offer for any consumers who wish to taste something different. Coffee is even offered in a decaffeinated version for those who enjoy the smell and taste of coffee, but wish to stay away from the caffeine. In addition to the many versions and huge variety of flavors, coffee is also offered in an iced/slush version, as well as served with actual ice cubes which have both become a popular alternative to the traditional cup of coffee. Many businesses, both small and big, thrive on the sole sale of coffee and coffee related products (mugs, traveling cups, etc.). The desire to constantly innovate shows that the coffee industry is willing to reach out to the personal preferences and tastes of a nation of coffee drinkers.
    Coffee is a multi-billion dollar industry that shows signs of continued growth. In the United States alone, hundreds of millions of people drink coffee on a regular basis. It can be to start their day, a midday boost to get them through the remaining hours of their day, or even a comfort drink. Whatever the reason may be, there are millions of people nationwide who have trouble functioning without the caffeine spike that coffee offers. Today, coffee companies are setting out to satisfy the desires of coffee drinkers by offering a huge and seemingly endless variety of new flavors. Of course there is the traditional cream and sugar, or lack thereof (black coffee), but now, anyone interested in trying new flavors will find a much larger selection than ever imagined. Flavors such as Hazelnut, French Vanilla, Chocolate, Dark Roast, Apple Cinnamon, Amaretto, and Butternut, are only a small fraction of what coffee companies have to offer for any consumers who wish to taste something different. Coffee is even offered in a decaffeinated version for those who enjoy the smell and taste of coffee, but wish to stay away from the caffeine. In addition to the many versions and huge variety of flavors, coffee is also offered in an iced/slush version, as well as served with actual ice cubes which have both become a popular alternative to the traditional cup of coffee. Many businesses, both small and big, thrive on the sole sale of coffee and coffee related products (mugs, traveling cups, etc.). The desire to constantly innovate shows that the coffee industry is willing to reach out to the personal preferences and tastes of a nation of coffee drinkers.
    Coffee is a multi-billion dollar industry that shows signs of continued growth. In the United States alone, hundreds of millions of people drink coffee on a regular basis. It can be to start their day, a midday boost to get them through the remaining hours of their day, or even a comfort drink. Whatever the reason may be, there are millions of people nationwide who have trouble functioning without the caffeine spike that coffee offers. Today, coffee companies are setting out to satisfy the desires of coffee drinkers by offering a huge and seemingly endless variety of new flavors. Of course there is the traditional cream and sugar, or lack thereof (black coffee), but now, anyone interested in trying new flavors will find a much larger selection than ever imagined. Flavors such as Hazelnut, French Vanilla, Chocolate, Dark Roast, Apple Cinnamon, Amaretto, and Butternut, are only a small fraction of what coffee companies have to offer for any consumers who wish to taste something different. Coffee is even offered in a decaffeinated version for those who enjoy the smell and taste of coffee, but wish to stay away from the caffeine. In addition to the many versions and huge variety of flavors, coffee is also offered in an iced/slush version, as well as served with actual ice cubes which have both become a popular alternative to the traditional cup of coffee. Many businesses, both small and big, thrive on the sole sale of coffee and coffee related products (mugs, traveling cups, etc.). The desire to constantly innovate shows that the coffee industry is willing to reach out to the personal preferences and tastes of a nation of coffee drinkers.
    Coffee is a multi-billion dollar industry that shows signs of continued growth. In the United States alone, hundreds of millions of people drink coffee on a regular basis. It can be to start their day, a midday boost to get them through the remaining hours of their day, or even a comfort drink. Whatever the reason may be, there are millions of people nationwide who have trouble functioning without the caffeine spike that coffee offers. Today, coffee companies are setting out to satisfy the desires of coffee drinkers by offering a huge and seemingly endless variety of new flavors. Of course there is the traditional cream and sugar, or lack thereof (black coffee), but now, anyone interested in trying new flavors will find a much larger selection than ever imagined. Flavors such as Hazelnut, French Vanilla, Chocolate, Dark Roast, Apple Cinnamon, Amaretto, and Butternut, are only a small fraction of what coffee companies have to offer for any consumers who wish to taste something different. Coffee is even offered in a decaffeinated version for those who enjoy the smell and taste of coffee, but wish to stay away from the caffeine. In addition to the many versions and huge variety of flavors, coffee is also offered in an iced/slush version, as well as served with actual ice cubes which have both become a popular alternative to the traditional cup of coffee. Many businesses, both small and big, thrive on the sole sale of coffee and coffee related products (mugs, traveling cups, etc.). The desire to constantly innovate shows that the coffee industry is willing to reach out to the personal preferences and tastes of a nation of coffee drinkers.
    Coffee is a multi-billion dollar industry that shows signs of continued growth. In the United States alone, hundreds of millions of people drink coffee on a regular basis. It can be to start their day, a midday boost to get them through the remaining hours of their day, or even a comfort drink. Whatever the reason may be, there are millions of people nationwide who have trouble functioning without the caffeine spike that coffee offers. Today, coffee companies are setting out to satisfy the desires of coffee drinkers by offering a huge and seemingly endless variety of new flavors. Of course there is the traditional cream and sugar, or lack thereof (black coffee), but now, anyone interested in trying new flavors will find a much larger selection than ever imagined. Flavors such as Hazelnut, French Vanilla, Chocolate, Dark Roast, Apple Cinnamon, Amaretto, and Butternut, are only a small fraction of what coffee companies have to offer for any consumers who wish to taste something different. Coffee is even offered in a decaffeinated version for those who enjoy the smell and taste of coffee, but wish to stay away from the caffeine. In addition to the many versions and huge variety of flavors, coffee is also offered in an iced/slush version, as well as served with actual ice cubes which have both become a popular alternative to the traditional cup of coffee. Many businesses, both small and big, thrive on the sole sale of coffee and coffee related products (mugs, traveling cups, etc.). The desire to constantly innovate shows that the coffee industry is willing to reach out to the personal preferences and tastes of a nation of coffee drinkers.Coffee is a multi-billion dollar industry that shows signs of continued growth. In the United States alone, hundreds of millions of people drink coffee on a regular basis. It can be to start their day, a midday boost to get them through the remaining hours of their day, or even a comfort drink. Whatever the reason may be, there are millions of people nationwide who have trouble functioning without the caffeine spike that coffee offers. Today, coffee companies are setting out to satisfy the desires of coffee drinkers by offering a huge and seemingly endless variety of new flavors. Of course there is the traditional cream and sugar, or lack thereof (black coffee), but now, anyone interested in trying new flavors will find a much larger selection than ever imagined. Flavors such as Hazelnut, French Vanilla, Chocolate, Dark Roast, Apple Cinnamon, Amaretto, and Butternut, are only a small fraction of what coffee companies have to offer for any consumers who wish to taste something different. Coffee is even offered in a decaffeinated version for those who enjoy the smell and taste of coffee, but wish to stay away from the caffeine. In addition to the many versions and huge variety of flavors, coffee is also offered in an iced/slush version, as well as served with actual ice cubes which have both become a popular alternative to the traditional cup of coffee. Many businesses, both small and big, thrive on the sole sale of coffee and coffee related products (mugs, traveling cups, etc.). The desire to constantly innovate shows that the coffee industry is willing to reach out to the personal preferences and tastes of a nation of coffee drinkers.
    Coffee is a multi-billion dollar industry that shows signs of continued growth. In the United States alone, hundreds of millions of people drink coffee on a regular basis. It can be to start their day, a midday boost to get them through the remaining hours of their day, or even a comfort drink. Whatever the reason may be, there are millions of people nationwide who have trouble functioning without the caffeine spike that coffee offers. Today, coffee companies are setting out to satisfy the desires of coffee drinkers by offering a huge and seemingly endless variety of new flavors. Of course there is the traditional cream and sugar, or lack thereof (black coffee), but now, anyone interested in trying new flavors will find a much larger selection than ever imagined. Flavors such as Hazelnut, French Vanilla, Chocolate, Dark Roast, Apple Cinnamon, Amaretto, and Butternut, are only a small fraction of what coffee companies have to offer for any consumers who wish to taste something different. Coffee is even offered in a decaffeinated version for those who enjoy the smell and taste of coffee, but wish to stay away from the caffeine. In addition to the many versions and huge variety of flavors, coffee is also offered in an iced/slush version, as well as served with actual ice cubes which have both become a popular alternative to the traditional cup of coffee. Many businesses, both small and big, thrive on the sole sale of coffee and coffee related products (mugs, traveling cups, etc.). The desire to constantly innovate shows that the coffee industry is willing to reach out to the personal preferences and tastes of a nation of coffee drinkers.Coffee is a multi-billion dollar industry that shows signs of continued growth. In the United States alone, hundreds of millions of people drink coffee on a regular basis. It can be to start their day, a midday boost to get them through the remaining hours of their day, or even a comfort drink. Whatever the reason may be, there are millions of people nationwide who have trouble functioning without the caffeine spike that coffee offers. Today, coffee companies are setting out to satisfy the desires of coffee drinkers by offering a huge and seemingly endless variety of new flavors. Of course there is the traditional cream and sugar, or lack thereof (black coffee), but now, anyone interested in trying new flavors will find a much larger selection than ever imagined. Flavors such as Hazelnut, French Vanilla, Chocolate, Dark Roast, Apple Cinnamon, Amaretto, and Butternut, are only a small fraction of what coffee companies have to offer for any consumers who wish to taste something different. Coffee is even offered in a decaffeinated version for those who enjoy the smell and taste of coffee, but wish to stay away from the caffeine. In addition to the many versions and huge variety of flavors, coffee is also offered in an iced/slush version, as well as served with actual ice cubes which have both become a popular alternative to the traditional cup of coffee. Many businesses, both small and big, thrive on the sole sale of coffee and coffee related products (mugs, traveling cups, etc.). The desire to constantly innovate shows that the coffee industry is willing to reach out to the personal preferences and tastes of a nation of coffee drinkers.Coffee is a multi-billion dollar industry that shows signs of continued growth. In the United States alone, hundreds of millions of people drink coffee on a regular basis. It can be to start their day, a midday boost to get them through the remaining hours of their day, or even a comfort drink. Whatever the reason may be, there are millions of people nationwide who have trouble functioning without the caffeine spike that coffee offers. Today, coffee companies are setting out to satisfy the desires of coffee drinkers by offering a huge and seemingly endless variety of new flavors. Of course there is the traditional cream and sugar, or lack thereof (black coffee), but now, anyone interested in trying new flavors will find a much larger selection than ever imagined. Flavors such as Hazelnut, French Vanilla, Chocolate, Dark Roast, Apple Cinnamon, Amaretto, and Butternut, are only a small fraction of what coffee companies have to offer for any consumers who wish to taste something different. Coffee is even offered in a decaffeinated version for those who enjoy the smell and taste of coffee, but wish to stay away from the caffeine. In addition to the many versions and huge variety of flavors, coffee is also offered in an iced/slush version, as well as served with actual ice cubes which have both become a popular alternative to the traditional cup of coffee. Many businesses, both small and big, thrive on the sole sale of coffee and coffee related products (mugs, traveling cups, etc.). The desire to constantly innovate shows that the coffee industry is willing to reach out to the personal preferences and tastes of a nation of coffee drinkers.Coffee is a multi-billion dollar industry that shows signs of continued growth. In the United States alone, hundreds of millions of people drink coffee on a regular basis. It can be to start their day, a midday boost to get them through the remaining hours of their day, or even a comfort drink. Whatever the reason may be, there are millions of people nationwide who have trouble functioning without the caffeine spike that coffee offers. Today, coffee companies are setting out to satisfy the desires of coffee drinkers by offering a huge and seemingly endless variety of new flavors. Of course there is the traditional cream and sugar, or lack thereof (black coffee), but now, anyone interested in trying new flavors will find a much larger selection than ever imagined. Flavors such as Hazelnut, French Vanilla, Chocolate, Dark Roast, Apple Cinnamon, Amaretto, and Butternut, are only a small fraction of what coffee companies have to offer for any consumers who wish to taste something different. Coffee is even offered in a decaffeinated version for those who enjoy the smell and taste of coffee, but wish to stay away from the caffeine. In addition to the many versions and huge variety of flavors, coffee is also offered in an iced/slush version, as well as served with actual ice cubes which have both become a popular alternative to the traditional cup of coffee. Many businesses, both small and big, thrive on the sole sale of coffee and coffee related products (mugs, traveling cups, etc.). The desire to constantly innovate shows that the coffee industry is willing to reach out to the personal preferences and tastes of a nation of coffee drinkers.Coffee is a multi-billion dollar industry that shows signs of continued growth. In the United States alone, hundreds of millions of people drink coffee on a regular basis. It can be to start their day, a midday boost to get them through the remaining hours of their day, or even a comfort drink. Whatever the reason may be, there are millions of people nationwide who have trouble functioning without the caffeine spike that coffee offers. Today, coffee companies are setting out to satisfy the desires of coffee drinkers by offering a huge and seemingly endless variety of new flavors. Of course there is the traditional cream and sugar, or lack thereof (black coffee), but now, anyone interested in trying new flavors will find a much larger selection than ever imagined. Flavors such as Hazelnut, French Vanilla, Chocolate, Dark Roast, Apple Cinnamon, Amaretto, and Butternut, are only a small fraction of what coffee companies have to offer for any consumers who wish to taste something different. Coffee is even offered in a decaffeinated version for those who enjoy the smell and taste of coffee, but wish to stay away from the caffeine. In addition to the many versions and huge variety of flavors, coffee is also offered in an iced/slush version, as well as served with actual ice cubes which have both become a popular alternative to the traditional cup of coffee. Many businesses, both small and big, thrive on the sole sale of coffee and coffee related products (mugs, traveling cups, etc.). The desire to constantly innovate shows that the coffee industry is willing to reach out to the personal preferences and tastes of a nation of coffee drinkers.Coffee is a multi-billion dollar industry that shows signs of continued growth. In the United States alone, hundreds of millions of people drink coffee on a regular basis. It can be to start their day, a midday boost to get them through the remaining hours of their day, or even a comfort drink. Whatever the reason may be, there are millions of people nationwide who have trouble functioning without the caffeine spike that coffee offers. Today, coffee companies are setting out to satisfy the desires of coffee drinkers by offering a huge and seemingly endless variety of new flavors. Of course there is the traditional cream and sugar, or lack thereof (black coffee), but now, anyone interested in trying new flavors will find a much larger selection than ever imagined. Flavors such as Hazelnut, French Vanilla, Chocolate, Dark Roast, Apple Cinnamon, Amaretto, and Butternut, are only a small fraction of what coffee companies have to offer for any consumers who wish to taste something different. Coffee is even offered in a decaffeinated version for those who enjoy the smell and taste of coffee, but wish to stay away from the caffeine. In addition to the many versions and huge variety of flavors, coffee is also offered in an iced/slush version, as well as served with actual ice cubes which have both become a popular alternative to the traditional cup of coffee. Many businesses, both small and big, thrive on the sole sale of coffee and coffee related products (mugs, traveling cups, etc.). The desire to constantly innovate shows that the coffee industry is willing to reach out to the personal preferences and tastes of a nation of coffee drinkers.Coffee is a multi-billion dollar industry that shows signs of continued growth. In the United States alone, hundreds of millions of people drink coffee on a regular basis. It can be to start their day, a midday boost to get them through the remaining hours of their day, or even a comfort drink. Whatever the reason may be, there are millions of people nationwide who have trouble functioning without the caffeine spike that coffee offers. Today, coffee companies are setting out to satisfy the desires of coffee drinkers by offering a huge and seemingly endless variety of new flavors. Of course there is the traditional cream and sugar, or lack thereof (black coffee), but now, anyone interested in trying new flavors will find a much larger selection than ever imagined. Flavors such as Hazelnut, French Vanilla, Chocolate, Dark Roast, Apple Cinnamon, Amaretto, and Butternut, are only a small fraction of what coffee companies have to offer for any consumers who wish to taste something different. Coffee is even offered in a decaffeinated version for those who enjoy the smell and taste of coffee, but wish to stay away from the caffeine. In addition to the many versions and huge variety of flavors, coffee is also offered in an iced/slush version, as well as served with actual ice cubes which have both become a popular alternative to the traditional cup of coffee. Many businesses, both small and big, thrive on the sole sale of coffee and coffee related products (mugs, traveling cups, etc.). The desire to constantly innovate shows that the coffee industry is willing to reach out to the personal preferences and tastes of a nation of coffee drinkers.Coffee is a multi-billion dollar industry that shows signs of continued growth. In the United States alone, hundreds of millions of people drink coffee on a regular basis. It can be to start their day, a midday boost to get them through the remaining hours of their day, or even a comfort drink. Whatever the reason may be, there are millions of people nationwide who have trouble functioning without the caffeine spike that coffee offers. Today, coffee companies are setting out to satisfy the desires of coffee drinkers by offering a huge and seemingly endless variety of new flavors. Of course there is the traditional cream and sugar, or lack thereof (black coffee), but now, anyone interested in trying new flavors will find a much larger selection than ever imagined. Flavors such as Hazelnut, French Vanilla, Chocolate, Dark Roast, Apple Cinnamon, Amaretto, and Butternut, are only a small fraction of what coffee companies have to offer for any consumers who wish to taste something different. Coffee is even offered in a decaffeinated version for those who enjoy the smell and taste of coffee, but wish to stay away from the caffeine. In addition to the many versions and huge variety of flavors, coffee is also offered in an iced/slush version, as well as served with actual ice cubes which have both become a popular alternative to the traditional cup of coffee. Many businesses, both small and big, thrive on the sole sale of coffee and coffee related products (mugs, traveling cups, etc.). The desire to constantly innovate shows that the coffee industry is willing to reach out to the personal preferences and tastes of a nation of coffee drinkers.Coffee is a multi-billion dollar industry that shows signs of continued growth. In the United States alone, hundreds of millions of people drink coffee on a regular basis. It can be to start their day, a midday boost to get them through the remaining hours of their day, or even a comfort drink. Whatever the reason may be, there are millions of people nationwide who have trouble functioning without the caffeine spike that coffee offers. Today, coffee companies are setting out to satisfy the desires of coffee drinkers by offering a huge and seemingly endless variety of new flavors. Of course there is the traditional cream and sugar, or lack thereof (black coffee), but now, anyone interested in trying new flavors will find a much larger selection than ever imagined. Flavors such as Hazelnut, French Vanilla, Chocolate, Dark Roast, Apple Cinnamon, Amaretto, and Butternut, are only a small fraction of what coffee companies have to offer for any consumers who wish to taste something different. Coffee is even offered in a decaffeinated version for those who enjoy the smell and taste of coffee, but wish to stay away from the caffeine. In addition to the many versions and huge variety of flavors, coffee is also offered in an iced/slush version, as well as served with actual ice cubes which have both become a popular alternative to the traditional cup of coffee. Many businesses, both small and big, thrive on the sole sale of coffee and coffee related products (mugs, traveling cups, etc.). The desire to constantly innovate shows that the coffee industry is willing to reach out to the personal preferences and tastes of a nation of coffee drinkers.Coffee is a multi-billion dollar industry that shows signs of continued growth. In the United States alone, hundreds of millions of people drink coffee on a regular basis. It can be to start their day, a midday boost to get them through the remaining hours of their day, or even a comfort drink. Whatever the reason may be, there are millions of people nationwide who have trouble functioning without the caffeine spike that coffee offers. Today, coffee companies are setting out to satisfy the desires of coffee drinkers by offering a huge and seemingly endless variety of new flavors. Of course there is the traditional cream and sugar, or lack thereof (black coffee), but now, anyone interested in trying new flavors will find a much larger selection than ever 
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667829/how-to-create-a-sticky-navigation-bar-that-becomes-fixed-to-the-top-after-scroll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
ul {
   position: sticky; 
   top: 0;
}
```

If you are not going to support IE and Edge I think. You can check that at `https://caniuse.com/`.

Answer (score 0):

> position will fix the navbar when your navbar reaches to the top.

This will help you,

```
.ul{
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  position: sticky;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Try this

Comment: this places the navbar on top, i need the nav under the video

Comment: You got the right answer Anyways I  updated @AchielVolckaert